# Bookmarklet to load data cross domain

Tags: firefox, bookmarklet

I realise there are cross domain restrictions with javascript and I believe I have run into them but I am not sure:

I am trying to create a bookmarklet that loads a zip-file from another domain to be processed internally. I.e. not to be saved. - Is this possible?

My approach so far is along the lines of:

```
var xhr2_blob = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr2_blob.open('GET', downloadUrlCrossDomain, true);
xhr2_blob.responseType = 'blob';
```

Unfortunately while readyState changes to 4, the status property remains 0 rather than changing to 200.

Note: I have access to neither of the servers.

Comment: run the bookmarklet directly on the other site

Answer (score 0):

if i run this script from a boomarket i will get a access error unless i am on google.com when i run it.. Get it?

```
url = "https://www.google.com"
function process(){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", url, true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4){
                alert(xhr.responseText)
            }
        }
        xhr.send();
    }
```